# Why does the Java compiler add visibility bridge methods for public methods defined in package-private super types?

Tags: java, javac, java-bridge-method

I am wondering why the Java compiler would add a bridge method for the `foo` method here:

```
public class Outer {

  class SuperClass {
    public void foo() { }
  }

  public class SubClass extends SuperClass { }
}
```

The `foo` method is compiled to be `public` in the `SuperClass` type. Nevertheless, the `SubClass` method redefines the method as a bridge to the very same method. I wonder why this bridge is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rational for adding this bridge method is a corner-case in the Java reflection API which would cause an `IllegalAccessException` without the bridge method being added. The bug is documented here in [Oracle's bug tracker](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6342411):

A reflective invocation

```
Subclass.class.getMethod("foo").invoke(new Subclass())
```

was not processed correctly from other packages than that of `SuperClass` without the bridge method fix as the Java run time could not figure out that the invocation of the `foo` method was legal. The reflection processes visibility checks on a method's declaring type which would then erroneously conclude that the method was not visible and its invocation illegal.

According to the documentation on the ticket, there was no easier work-around. A non-reflective invocation was however processed normally, even before the bridge method was added.